# Expanding div to show hidden inner content

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm new to Angular, and rusty with HTML and CSS, so I was wondering how I could create a "write post" text area (similar to facebook or medium.com), whereby the user is first presented with a small "write here" box, and then when they click on the writing area, the div expands, and then new controls are shown.  I've added some screen shots below to help explain what I mean.

I understand how to expand divs and do DOM manipulation through Angular via directives, but I'm just wondering how I should approach this problem at a higher level.

[image: untouched state]

then the user clicks on the above, and the div expands, and inner content is shown:

[image: after user clicks on the writing area]

I have the below in my index.ejs:

```
    <div write-post-box id="write_post_box">
        <p>Write here...</p>
    </div>
```

and the below directive in my angular file:

```
app.directive('writePostBox', function() {
    return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.click(function() {
            element.css('height', '200px');
        });
    }
    };
});
```

Comment: Please add some relevant code

Comment: I've added the limited code I have, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ngFocus` and `ngBlur` directives - [check them](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive) - and from those functions you could set height of the `textarea`/`div`.